# .htaccess removing .html won't work with one page

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

Before i had my site written as .php and i could easily remove .php on end and connect to pages without typing .php on end, but now i got new page that is written as .html and i want to do same. It took me some time to find working code for .htaccess but sadly there is one problem. All pages work fine but when i try to access my help page i get "Error 301 - Access forbidden" for some reason.

For example i type:
example.com/help (original example.com/help.html)
but what it does it turn to:
example.com/help/ and give me that 301 error.

This is my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.html

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{httpS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{http_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

So i'm not sure how to fix this (if it's possible), so if anyone has any ideas on how to fix it please let me know. If it's not possible for some reason are there any other pages that this won't work on? I'm still working on site so i can rename help page to helpcenter or something like that but i'm not sure if that effect any other files.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 has supported extension masking via the `+MultiViews` option for a while now. In my experience, it's much easier to implement than custom rewrite rules.

If you're set on using rewrites, however, make sure you don't have a `help` directory. `-Indexes` will give it a 401 if there's no index.html file inside.

Comment: Sadly i don't really know what is "Apache2" or how to write that rules, so i'm kinda looking for some examples. If this problem is only related to "help.html" then it's not really problem as i can rename it to helpcenter (or will that be problem too?)